# how to exclude packages from cygwin install?

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to do a **Quiet** install of cygwin category **All**, but running into some errors:

```
package git comparing versions 1.8.3.1-1 and 1.7.9-1, result was 1
package git-completion comparing versions 1.8.3.1-1 and 1.7.9-1, result was 1
package git-cvs comparing versions 1.8.3.1-1 and 1.7.9-1, result was 1
...
```

My command line:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -R c:\dev\cygwin\root -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg -q -C All
```

Is it possible to specify packages to exclude when choosing the **All** category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to exclude the packages using the Cygwin UI.

I couldn't find a way to exclude them in quiet mode.